# Unable to properly adjust display arrangement for portrait monitor next to landscape monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 20.04

I am trying to match my display setup to my physical setup. I am on Ubuntu 20.04LTS. My left monitor is in portrait mode, and my right one is in landscape mode.

Here is [my current setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg0aD.png). This does not accurately reflect my physical setup, but it is the best i can do for now.

My physical setup looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3Nku.png). But when I apply these changes to my settings, my portrait monitor turns off, and then my main landscape monitor stretches out so that I can scroll around the desktop.

I have tried other arrangements within the display settings, and some of them create similar problems. In some cases, my monitors will stack upon themselves and both screens are visible.

**lspci | grep VGA**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106M [GeForce RTX 2060 Mobile] (rev a1)
```

**xrandr**

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3000 x 1920, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected 1080x1920+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1080+840 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
eDP-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080    240.00 +  60.00  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Having the same issue here. Could you edit your question and add the output of `lspci | grep VGA` and the output of `xrandr`. PS! Remember to surround the output by a blank line, and indent the output by four spaces so it shows as "code".

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm.

Lenovo P50 laptop with two external monitors (USB-C & HDMI), one in portrait mode.

Recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which did not have this issue, to 20.04 LTS.

The "real estate" of the two landscape monitors bleeds into the right hand monitor and I'm able to "scroll" vertically (which I don't want). Maximizing windows will make the window display on two monitors partly.

***Workaround***: Change the monitor in portrait mode back to landscape mode. Not what I want but at least it gives me a working setup.

Setup left to right (with portrait mode):

1. Laptop monitor 1920x1080 (16:9) - landscape
2. Samsung 34" 3440x1440 (21:9) - landscape - USB-C
3. Acer 24" 1920x1080 (16:9) - portrait - HDMI

[image: monitor configuration]

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M] (rev a2)
```

**Driver** recently installed with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

```
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - distro non-free recommended
```

Recently changed from `nvidia-driver-435` which had the same problem.

**xrandr**

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 7280 x 1920, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected 1080x1920+5360+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm panning 1920x1920+5360+0 tracking 7280x1920+0+0 border 0/0/0/0
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected 1920x1080+0+840 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm panning 2760x1080+0+840 tracking 7280x1920+0+0 border 0/0/0/0
   1920x1080     60.02*+  48.00  
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 connected primary 3440x1440+1920+480 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 797mm x 333mm panning 4280x1440+1920+480 tracking 7280x1920+0+0 border 0/0/0/0
   3440x1440     59.97 +  99.98    49.99* 
   2560x1440     59.95  
   2560x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```